# Get property value type of each value in a class

Tags: c#, reflection

How can I get the property value type of each property in a class?

```
this.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(p => {
    switch(typeof(p.GetValue(this, null))) {
        case float:
            ...
            break;
        case string:
            ...
            break;
    }
});
```

This produces the error `Cannot resolve symbol p`

**SOLUTION:** I ended up going with LINQ to SQL. Just cleaner and easier to deal :). Thanks Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get that as a problem - I get:

```
Test.cs(12,29): error CS1026: ) expected
Test.cs(12,42): error CS1514: { expected
Test.cs(12,42): error CS1525: Invalid expression term ')'
Test.cs(12,44): error CS1002: ; expected
Test.cs(13,9): error CS1525: Invalid expression term 'case'
Test.cs(13,19): error CS1001: Identifier expected
Test.cs(13,19): error CS1525: Invalid expression term ':'
Test.cs(13,20): error CS1002: ; expected
Test.cs(15,9): error CS1525: Invalid expression term 'case'
Test.cs(15,20): error CS1001: Identifier expected
Test.cs(15,20): error CS1525: Invalid expression term ':'
Test.cs(15,21): error CS1002: ; expected
```

You can't switch on types. Using `ForEach` like that in general is fine though.

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Test
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }    
    public int Bar { get; set; }

    public void DumpProperties()
    {
        this.GetType().GetProperties().ToList()
            .ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p.Name,
                                            p.GetValue(this, null)));
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        new Test { Foo = "Hi", Bar = 20 }.DumpProperties();
    }
}
```

Now admittedly I generally *wouldn't* use `ForEach` here - I'd just use a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var property in GetType().GetProperties())
{
    // Use property
}
```

Personally I think that's cleaner, simpler to read, and easier to debug.

Comment: I'm building a sql string but I need to know what the types of each property are so I know how to build each where clause. Any suggestions?

Comment: @bflemi3: Personally I'd use LINQ instead of building SQL, but if you can't do that, use a `foreach` loop - it'll be simpler. You could use a `Dictionary<Type, Action<...>>` (for suitable `...`) to indicate what to do on a per-type basis.

Comment: Decided that's what I'm doing, using LINQ to SQL. Thanks again Jon!

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't use `switch` on `Type` - it does not have constant values to put in `case`.
2. If you still want your `switch`, and you're working with well-known set of types (i.e., *system types*), you can use `p.PropertyType.GetTypeCode()` which returns `enum`.